# how to use xmlstarlet to fully duplicate a node?

Tags: duplicates, xmlstarlet

The node has attributes and subnodes and everything else it can have, I need to duplicate it all.
After duplicated, I will change a few values on the new node, so I need to be able to uniquely target it also.

Comment: as some code for batter understanding.

Comment: @CodeChanger it could be the activity node of this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/18082610/5648245 , I will see if I prepare something as soon I get to my pc

Comment: seems necessary to use xslt, like at http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xsl_apply_templates.asp, but the simplest way to do that is not quite clear... Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29298507/xmlstarlet-xinclude-xslt